# regular expression in API google maps

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract the data " lng" from the API Geocode

```
"location" : {
               "lat" : -33.4419266,
               "lng" : -70.64956029999999
              },
```

and, I tried this:

```
regex.Pattern = "location(?:.|\n)*?""lng"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
```

but for moment, I get "70" and not "-70.64956029999999". 
How I can get the full number? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using RegEx on json will eventually drive you crazy...

```
Sub Test()

    Dim j, s As Object
    j = "{location : {lat : -33.4419266, lng : -70.64956029999999}}"

    Set s = CreateObject("scriptcontrol")
    s.Language = "javascript"

    s.eval "var o = (" & j & ");"

    Debug.Print s.eval("o.location.lng") '>> -70.6495603

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
regex.Pattern = "(?:""lng"" : )([^\n\r]+)"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.